# Strange issue while summing time interval and date in Swift 3

Tags: swift, ambiguous

While trying to sum date and timeinterval i am getting Ambigous use of operator + error. How can it be fixed?

```
func +(date: Date, timeInterval: Int) -> Date {
    return date + TimeInterval(timeInterval)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you attempting to define such a `+` operator? Swift already provides one.

The following works just fine:

```
let date = Date()
let interval = TimeInterval(45)
let newDate = date + interval
```

And the code you posted in your question works just fine for me.

```
func +(date: Date, timeInterval: Int) -> Date {
    return date + TimeInterval(timeInterval)
}

let date = Date()
let interval = 45
let anotherDate = date + interval
```

Comment: you are checking it in swift 3 or 2? I am trying to migrate from 2 to 3 and getting this error

Comment: Swift 3. All of that code was run in the Swift playground of Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Sounds like the custom `+` operator was required in Swift 2 but is no longer required in Swift 3.